# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not connecting to wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Kernel - 4.4.0-43-generic

I installed Ubuntu 6 months ago as a dual boot with Windows 10, didn't face much problems connecting to home wifi, even though connection part is not smooth at times, sometimes I need to manually select my home wifi, but it used to connect.

Now in the last 2 days, it's not connecting at all, tried some solutions posted online, but no luck. Tried with a different kernel during startup, still the same problem.

How do I solve this problem?

PS: I selected tag as 14.04, since I couldn't just ubuntu or 16.04

Update: Ubuntu Pastebin link - http://paste.ubuntu.com/23374081/

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) first, then [edit] your answer with the appropriate info.

Comment: @Fabby I got the wireless-info file after executing the command, not sure what to do next.

Comment: [edit] your answer and copy-paste the info there or paste it to http://paste.ubuntu.com and leave the link to your paste in your answer.

Comment: @Fabby I pasted in paste.ubuntu and provided the link in my original post. Confused how this will help me.

Comment: It does not help you directly: it helps us by giving us more information what is wrong with your setup so we can help you. (going through it now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnostic you provided shows that your Wireless card is hard blocked.

Depending on the Brand and Model, this might be a function key with a little antenna or a physical switch on the front or side of your computer.

Press that and you'll be back on-line!

Comment: fqvour returned!  Q upvoted!  **;-)**